# Remove all account limits from mysql workbench

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-workbench

The idea is to connect to a mysql database on a remote system using plain `jdbc` in java(only using servlets,no frameworks or orm involved).I manage to connect at first,but then the account limit kicks in and I have to restart the server,I would like to remove some of these limits and set it to infinite?

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: User 'root' has exceeded the 'max_connections_per_hour' resource (current value: 100)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by using MySQL workbench. 
Connect to your database with root user. 
Choose "management" --> "users and privileges". 
Select needed user, then select "acount limits". Change "Max. queries" to 0.

Also it can be done from command line
Example:

```
grant usage on *.* to 'root'@'localhost' with MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0;
```

Comment: I get this `error` when i try from `command line` `ERROR 1226 (42000): User 'root' has exceeded the 'max_questions' resource (curre
nt value: 1000)`